# install libxml2 on linux, run configure failed

Tags: linux, libxml2

I downloaded libxml2-2.9.3.tar.gz
After unzip it, I ran configure, but got the following errors.

```
~/libxml2-2.9.3]$ sh ./configure --help
: command not found4: 
./configure: line 29: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
'/configure: line 29: `     ;;
```

I tried `sh ./configure --prefix=/home/mydir/libxml2-2.9.3`,  got same error.
running `./configure --help` says `./configure: Command not found.`

Please help me to install the libxml2. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: don't run sh.   just do './configure' with whatever flags.

Comment: But './configure' says 'Command not found'.  Thanks!

Comment: What's your default shell (`/bin/sh`)?